# Missing section number in using cref for subsection

Tags: cleveref, subsection

I am using `\documentclass{IEEEtaes}`, and I want to use `\cref{}` to cross-reference a subsection in the document. However, it prints only subsection number without the section number.

For example, let's assume that there is `Section I. Introduction` and a subsection `I-A. Part of Intro`. When I use `\cref` for Section I-A., such as

```
\section{Introduction}
The part of Intro is in \Cref{subsec:pIntro}.

\subsection{Part of Intro}
\label{subsec:pIntro}
```

The output is "The part of Intro is in Section A."

How can I make this sentence print out as "The part of Intro is in Section I-A."?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the `IEEEtaes` document class available online? If so, where? Is the `IEEEtaes` class maybe based on the `IEEEtran` class? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Hi, the template can be downloaded using this [link](https://confcats-web-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/ieeeaess/documents/TAES+Template.zip).  I am using the version of "IEEE_TAES_orig-research." This can be also found in the TAES author information center: https://ieee-aess.org/publications/transactions-aes/author-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set a label format for subsections.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtaes}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\labelformat{subsection}{\thesection-#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
The part of Intro is in \Cref{subsec:pIntro}.

\subsection{Part of Intro}
\label{subsec:pIntro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful.. With just one single line, it works perfectly..